# How to add comments to Atlassian Confluence (Cloud) via REST API and preserve markup formatting?

Tags: confluence, confluence-rest-api

I have a comment in plain text file that contains Atlassian markup language, like this:

```
An {{Unexpected end of socket}} \\nis a *TCP/IP* error message.
```

When I submit a REST API request to add such a comment, using the following JSON blurb:

```
{"type": "comment", 
 "container": {"type": "page", 
               "id": "123456789", 
               "status": "current"}, 
"body": {"storage": {"value": "An {{Unexpected end of socket}} \\nis a *TCP/IP* error message.", 
"representation": "storage"}}}
```

it gets rendered as text with curly braces, asterisks and other markup taken literally (well, except that \\n gets removed which is also not good):

> An {{Unexpected end of socket}} is a *TCP/IP* error message.

Ideally I would like to see this in the Confluence comment:

An `Unexpected end of socket`
is a **TCP/IP** error message.

Any suggestions?

Thanks, Kirill

Answer (score 0):

The best way to ensure that your formatting comes out exactly how you want it would be to create a test page/comment with the formatting that you want and then extract the storageformat for that output. This will always give you the exact formatting idiosyncrasies that you need to apply to preserve your desired formatting.

As of the time of this writing you would need to be like this:

```
"<p /><ac:structured-macro ac:name=\"code\" ac:schema-version=\"1\" ac:macro-id=\"d14c8973-f1c3-4e76-a75e-ba8e8e1be3af\"><ac:plain-text-body><![CDATA[unexpected end of socket]]></ac:plain-text-body></ac:structured-macro><p />"
```